# Access Google Datastore via BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

It looks like [Querying Google Cloud Bigtable Data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-bigtable) is possible with BigQuery, with a url like:

> [https://googleapis.com/bigtable/projects/[PROJECT_ID]/instances/[INSTANCE_ID]/tables/[TABLE_NAME]](https://googleapis.com/bigtable/projects/%5BPROJECT_ID%5D/instances/%5BINSTANCE_ID%5D/tables/%5BTABLE_NAME%5D)

Even though Google Datastore is built on Google Bigtable, there's no indication of what the `PROJECT_ID`, `INSTANCE_ID` or `TABLE_NAME` would be, where

> [PROJECT_ID] is the project containing your Cloud Bigtable instance
>
> [INSTANCE_ID] is the Cloud Bigtable instance ID
>
> [TABLE_NAME] is the name of the table you're querying

Is connecting to Datastore via a live connection possible via BigQuery? (i.e. not just via datastore-backup)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BigQuery allows you to query below [sources](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.query.tableDefinitions.(key).sourceFormat)

- CSV files
- Google sheets
- Newline-delimited JSON
- Avro files
- **Google Cloud Datastore backups**
- [Beta] Google Cloud Bigtable

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery allows you to query below Google Cloud Datastore backups. But to do that you need create a table on BigQuery using the **Datastore backup**.

Follow the steps:

- **Step 1 -** Create a bucket on gcs to store your backup. ([link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/creating-buckets))
- **Step 2 -** Take a backup of datastore. ([link](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/console/datastore-backing-up-restoring))
- **Step 3 -** On Biguery load your backup creating a table ([link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-datastore))

Some considerations about **Step 3**:

- You need import table by table.
- The location will be the files ended on [Entity Name].backup_info.

  > **Ex:**
  >
  > gs://bck-kanjih/ag9zfmdvb2dsLWNpdC1nY3ByQQsSHF9BRV9EYXRhc3RvcmVBZG1pbl9PcGVyYXRpb24YwZ-rAwwLEhZfQUVfQmFja3VwX0luZm9ybWF0aW9uGAEM.**Conference.backup_info**